# Laravel 4 Eloquent - Utilize/Access ORM Relationship Properties in Query Builder

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

#### To begin...

...let me say that my ORM/Eloquent relationships are functioning 100% how I want them to thus far (outside of the query builder issue). I've changed around some naming conventions to make the example clearer, but the code remains the same otherwise.

The first example is working fine. The second snippet is where I try to explain what I'm having trouble accomplishing.

#### This is working fine. Using the $filter_text to query against the Person->title

```
$people = Person::with('best_friend', 'associates')
    ->orderBy($order_by, $order_dir)
    ->where( function($query) use ($active, $filter_text) {
        $query->where('active', $active);
        if ($filter_text) {
            // This is working fine/expected
            $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$filter_text%");
        }
    })
    ->paginate(25);
```

#### Looking closer at my where( function($query) ) using the closure...

```
[...]
->where( function($query) use ($active, $filter_text) {
        $query->where('active', $active);
        if ($filter_text) {

            // This is working fine/expected
            $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$filter_text%");

            /**
             * I want to use the same $filter_text to query against the $person->best_friend->name field
             *     Something like this
             */
            $query->orWhere('best_friend.name', 'LIKE', "%$filter_text%");

        }
    })
[...]
```

#### This is the error I'm getting

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'people.best_friend.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `people` where (`active` = ? and `title` LIKE ? or `best_friend`.`name` LIKE ?)) (Bindings: array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '%g%', 2 => '%g', ))

#### Note...

I have tried a few variations of using the Model's names, Model's ORM method names, and table names with variations on plural/singular/capital/etc... They all seem to return a similar error.

*When the results are output/accessed after the get()/paginate() method, all of the "best_friend" info is there and accessible.* **My question boils down to how to access this same data in the query builder.**

Any insight/thoughts are greatly appreciated. I hope the question at least makes sense.

Find me on Twitter: @ErikOnTheWeb

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want is to filter the main model collection (Person) when a relationship meets certain condition, so:

```
Model::with($relations)->whereHas('onerelation', function($query)
{
    $query->where($onerelation_field, $operator, $value);
})
->where($model_field, $operator, $value)
->get();
```

This returns a `Model`'s collection whose relationship `Onerelation` meets the specified condition (besides their own ones).